# How to generate the subimage which the size of region is fixed to 17x17 by using MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I'm beginner to MATLAB . Can you help me by this problem , when given a pixel (x,y) of the image , the original image size is 292x283. How to generate the subimage which the size of region is fixed to 17x17

Comment: Do you know how indexing works in MatLab?

Comment: agreed, see [here](http://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/matrix-indexing-in-matlab.html)

Answer (score 0):

Well you can try this:

```
>> A = imread('peppers.png');
>> size(A)
ans =
   384   512     1
A(1:17; 1:17) = [you can enter values here]
%For example
A(1:3;1:3) = [1 2 3; 1 2 3; 1 2 3];
```

Hope it will help you!